# как подключить BDA device в C++

Tags: c++, видео, драйвер

как подключить PCI Tuner в C++ чтоб потом работать с BDA.

Comment: у меня модел TBS6590.сказали тчо поддерживает BDA. а я не мог подключить Tuner чтоб потом написать свою программу.ну полючить например PAT,PMT...

Comment: Вероятно, для платы нужен драйвер и спецификация на него, чтобы вы могли с драйвером работать...

Comment: У вас узко специализированный вопрос. Добавте больше информации в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/728867/edit), не комментарий, чтобы знающие в этом толк могли найти вопрос. Метки C++ явно недостаточно.

Comment: и как это реализовать.

Comment: как работать с драйвером. я не пробовал и нет опыта